# Issue with setting/getting cookies in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

```
  def index
    # cookies.signed[:affiliate] = params[:affiliate] (this works)

    # (the following doesn't work at all)
    # cookies.delete(:affiliate) (temp delete to test if working properly)

    if !cookies.present?
      cookies.signed[:affiliate] = {
        id: params[:affiliate],
        expires: 30.days.from_now
      }
    end
  end
```

In my view I have the following to display the cookie:

```
  <%= cookies.signed[:affiliate] || 'none' %>
```

In routes I have:

```
  get ':affiliate', to: 'welcome#index'
```

What am I doing wrong? The use case is as follows:

1. Check for affiliate, if none, just ignore
2. If affiliate is set, store cookie with `30.days.from_now` expiry (don't allow this affiliate cookie to be overwritten by another affiliate unless expired.

Bonus question: For #2 do I have to explicitly check for `expires` datetime? or will `.present?` take care of this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this wasn't working is because `cookies` doesn't natively accept a hash. I used JSON.generate to create the cookie hash and JSON.parse to retrieve the data.

Also added in the `||` on the if conditional to handle overwriting expired cookies.

**Controller**

```
  def index
    if cookies.blank? || !(JSON.parse(cookies.signed[:affiliate])['expires'] > DateTime.now)
      cookies.signed[:affiliate] = JSON.generate(
        id: params[:affiliate],
        expires: 30.days.from_now
      )
    end
  end
```

**View**

```
  <%= JSON.parse(cookies.signed[:affiliate])['id'] %>
```

## Update Notice

This answer is partially working. After some testing I realized this works fine in Chrome but fails horribly in FireFox and Safari. No idea why... Someone feel free to comment. Thanks. Leaving the answer up because it does partially answer the question.